# How does tor find the nodes?

Tags: protocol

How does tor find the nodes? In other words, how does tor know which ip addresses are tor nodes and which aren't?

Answer (score 2):

The IPs and public keys of 9 directory authorities is compiled into Tor. Tor can download an initial list of all relays (the consensus) from those directory authorities.

See [this section of the Tor Project FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#KeyManagement).

> How do clients know what the relays are, and how do they know that they have the right keys for them?
>   [...] The directory authorities provide a signed list of all the known relays, [...] specifying their keys, locations, exit policies, and so on.
>   How do clients know what the directory authorities are?
>   The Tor software comes with a built-in list of location and public key for each directory authority.